# Applying read only permission to Kibana dashboard?

Tags: kibana

is there a way to set some sort of permissions when sharing kibana dashboard with others. I'm worried that someone would either delete it or make changes and save it. I googled but didn't find anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without shield, you can try to lock .kibana index on read only mode :

```
curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/.kibana/_settings' -d '{ "index.blocks.read_only" : true }'
```

It's working well, nobody can save/delete a dashboard / search / visualization. If user resize / move something on dashboard he can reset easily by bookmarking dashboard without parameters in url (or load it directly).

You can check more options about indices : https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.4/indices-update-settings.html

Comment: I know this is old and accepted answer, but i did this and my kibana isn't able to connect to ES , it says ; `Kibana: Unable to check for Kibana index ".kibana"  , Error: Authorization Exception`

could you see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35619931/fatal-error-while-locking-kibana-dashboard

Answer (score 4):

A lot has happened since the question was asked. Role based access control is now available in the community edition since May.

https://www.elastic.co/blog/security-for-elasticsearch-is-now-free

Answer (score 1):

When you go to the configure items of widgets and the dashboard (top right of the screen) you can set the editable flag to false. Beware though, now you cannot change it yourself anymore as well. Other options are available to provide the dashboard as a script, you can export it, enough options. But there is not something like, I am user x and I am the only one who can make changes.

Comment: Thank you Jettro. This does help a lot. Our company really likes Kibana but this was the major issue. How do you avoid others from overwriting dashboard.

Answer (score 0):

Well like what jettro said, "there is not something like, i am user x and i am the only one who can make changes"

With that being said, others can still overwrite your dashboard. They just need to save it and than open it up using editor. Once that is done, they can start editing it. Unless they are someone who don't know anything about it.